# More elegant way to create a python dictionary from a map object and list

Tags: python, list-comprehension, threadpoolexecutor, dictionary-comprehension

```
someList=['this','that','the_other','and_this']
timeFrame='hour'
getDatafromFile(some_string,time_frame):
    do some processing
    return dataframeObject
```

The end result is a dictionary with a keyed on the strings from someList and a value of the object returned from getDatafromFile.  The following code I wrote accomplishes this but it seems there should be an easier way with less lines of code.

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results=executor.map(getDatafromFile, [*someList],[timeFrame for i in range(len(someList))])
```

from this point forward is there a more elegant way to do this with less lines of code? Some sort of comprehension, perhaps. I thought about returning the string value and dataframe object back from the function, but it seems asinine to return back a parameter.

```
 pdDataList=[]
 for result in results:        
     pdDataList.append(result)
 df_dict=dict(zip(someList,pdDataList))
```

Comment: I can't really follow what your code does, but `[*l]` is equivalent to `l` if l is a list, and `[timeFrame] * len(someList)` would be more common than the comprehension in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict comprehension` syntax:

```py
{key: getDatafromFile(key, timeFrame) for key in someList}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the answer below, which can't work because the function has to be called by the threadpool executor, I got the idea of how to do the four lines of code in one line. Apparently a map object can be iterated as if it's a list.  I'm sure there's a dictionary comprehension equivalent but this is just as simple of a one liner:

```
df_dict=dict(zip(someList,results))
```

Thus the entire code is:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results=executor.map(getDatafromFile, [*someList],[timeFrame for i in range(len(someList))])
df_dict=dict(zip(someList,results))
```